# Calculate Image load progress not woking

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to show a progress bar while loading a big image as to how much its loaded but based on all my googling and search here , i've not found what i am looking for.

i am able to add loading gifs until its loaded then change using

```
$('img').load(function() {
    // my code here
}
```

i have also used :

```
 $(function() {
     $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: 37
     });
 })
```

But i do not know how to calculate how much % of the single image is loaded using javascript or jquery.

Any help is appreciated guys

Comment: You could send a shorter request first and time it.  For example, you know you'll need a 100kb image in the near future; so load it with no-cache, and measure the time it takes to receive.  Then with some simple math, you can estimate how long the other image will take, and have a sloppy progress bar (better than nothing).  Another option might be web sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, for loading your image as well as images and showing the progress:

```
$.each(arrayOfImageUrls, function(index, value) {
    $('<img></img>').attr('src', value)    //load image
        .load(function() {
            percentCounter = (index / arrayOfImageUrls.length) * 100;    //set the percentCounter after this image has loaded
            $('#yourProgressContainer').text(percentCounter + '%');
        });
});
```